# Is there a functional Jailbreak for iOS 4.1 on an iPhone 3GS?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone

I have an iPhone 3GS running 4.0.1 that is currently Jailbroken (using the Jailbreakme.com vulnerability a while back). While I don't care about any ability to unlock my phone -  I'm quite happy with AT&T - I do have LockInfo and one or two other jailbreak apps installed that I quite like. I'd like to update to 4.1 for the new features like GameCenter etc., but as far as I know, I'll lose my jailbreak if I do this.

Is there a working easy jailbreak for 4.1 at this time? If not, is one expected soon?

Comment: Is it legal to discuss this? I don't know.

Comment: Given that Jailbreaking for the purpose of running additional software has been explicitly authorized as a legal exception to DMCA restrictions by the Library of Congress, and given that we've had several other Jailbreak questions, I don't see why not.

Comment: There is a Stack Exchange proposal for Jail broken phones http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/18154/jailbreak-iphone-development?referrer=EuWVi6IpN0_KzzEhC7I-Qw2

Comment: @rjstelling - That's for Developers. I'm not, I'm just a user that wants to use Jailbreak apps on his phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that there currently is not one, although [rumours abound](http://www.redmondpie.com/jailbreak-ios-4.1-iphone-4-3gs-3g-ipod-touch-4g-bootrom-pwnagetool-4.1/) that one is coming up soon. The best place for "official" information is the [iPhone Dev-Team](http://blog.iphone-dev.org/). More direct/recent updates can be found by following various team members on Twitter. [MuscleNerd](http://twitter.com/musclenerd) is a good example. If other legitimate groups released anything solid, you will hear about it through them anyway (as is the case here: Chronic Dev Team seem reliable too). There are already fake sites springing up in anticipation of the next release; the important thing is not to use anything that hasn't been confirmed by them or that you have to pay for.

Additionally, if you have saved your SHSH blobs using Cydia on an already-jailbroken phone or [The Firmware Umbrella](http://thefirmwareumbrella.blogspot.com/), you can downgrade and jailbreak the old version. Normally this means you can upgrade using PwnageTool without losing your jailbreak, although I don't think the Dev-Team has released something compatible with 4.1 yet.

**UPDATE**

There is now a full jailbreak for 4.1 and later on 3GS. BigBoss maintains a [jailbreak table](http://thebigboss.org/jailbreak-now) which may be useful for updates at-a-glance. My understanding is that all current devices are now able to be jailbroken forever (greenpois0n/limera1n exploit), but  iPhone 4 and later model 3GS are sometimes tethered on iOS new releases (as of this edit: not tethered on 4.1, but currently - hopefully not for long - tethered on 4.2)